# angular ng-hide/ng-show evaluation of display:none

Tags: angularjs

Does angular evaluates the div that is hidden with ng-show/ng-hide.

ex.

```
Controller 
$scope.a=false;
$scope.b;

<div ng-show="a">
 Total : {{ b*2342342*34424442 }}
</div>
```

// Does total gets evaluated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It does. [**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/AUuuEvRvG61PTFrLWBbA?p=preview). You can use DOM inspector to find it

If you don't want that you should use [**ng-if**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf).

> The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

Additionally If you have multiple condition then you might use [**ng-switch**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)

> The ngSwitch directive is used to conditionally swap DOM structure on your template based on a scope expression. Elements within ngSwitch but without ngSwitchWhen or ngSwitchDefault directives will be preserved at the location as specified in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. It just hides the div if needed.

If you don't want the evaluation, use [`ng-if`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf).